# Visual Studio проблема (Source SDK)

Tags: visual-studio

Решил я разобраться как работать с Source SDK. Я скачал его, Source SDK Base 2006 и 2007[image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Для того, чтобы начать работу, мне нужно было скачать Microsoft Visual Studio (я скачал версию Enterprise 2015). В итоге, при запуске (все было сделано как [введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcFSY.jpg)сказано в гайде) пишет "Проектов: 0" и "Файл проекта был выгружен", чего, естественно, быть не должно (первая картинка). При нажатии "Установить отсутствующие компоненты", появляется это: (вторая картинка). Далее, если нажать "Установить", появляется окно. Ну и всё, при нажатии "ОК" ничего не происходит. Как устранить ошибку/установить отсутствующие элементы?
P.S. Всё пришлось сделать в одной картинке, ибо у меня "Недостаточно очков репутации чтобы добавлять больше двух ссылок".

Comment: Гайд по которому я всё делал: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PuHJRCZqqyY&feature=iv&src_vid=xVcw0ft_DO0&annotation_id=annotation_3698034721

Comment: вы когда устанавливали VS 2015 галочку для C++ ставили? Спрашиваю на всякий случай, кажется она по умолчанию отключена.